# How should I achieve this volumetrics lighting effect?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, lighting

I'm an intermediate blender user, and I am working on a scene myself. I just don't know how should I achieve the lighting effect in the image on the right below (left one is mine). I also need assistance on how to add volumetrics in this scene. I am using a transparent hdri in my scene.[image]

**EDIT:**
With help form the comments, I have changed a few settings and achieved close to what I want. The volumetrics (I added a rectangle with a principled volume shader) look good, but I still don't know how to achieve that sharp lighting effect I have shown with arrows in the picture above so I will wait for answers. I haev reached the end of my scene almost, so here's what I have done uptil now:[image] **EDIT 2:** After doing some research about this topic, I finally achieved the effect I wanted. Thanks for the help in the comments!

Comment: I think I would just crank up the HDRI strength a little, or maybe mess with camera exposure setting.  A world volume should work, stronger light will give a clearer effect as it passes through the volume.

Comment: @AllenSimpson I actually don't understand how to add volumetrics. And I can't seem to get that honeycomp lighting effect also. Along with that it has a lot of reflections on the water and a sharp cutout light coming out of the mouth of the cave. I am also using a sun lamp with a strenght of 5.

Comment: @brockmann This helps me a bit  but I don't understand how to get that cutout light effect. The image of my question has some arrows which tell what kind of cutout light effect I want.

Comment: Does this answer your question? - https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/214848/110840

Comment: Fantastic render.  Would you like this reopened so you can post your method as an answer?

Comment: @AllenSimpson Yes, that would be good. Thanks for the assistance in the comments and your remarks !)